# Counting number of occurences of ints in a list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do the following:
The function I'm writing takes list of tuples of ints `[(x,y),(i,j)...]` in range 0-6
I want to return an `[Int]` where each element is a count of how many of its
respective number were seen in the list.
e.g. `[(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)]` would return `[1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]`.

in other words, one 0, two 1's, two 2's 1 three and no 4s, 5s or 6s

```
countNumbers :: [(Int, Int)] -> [Int]  
countNumbers [] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

but am not sure how to go about this as I am somewhat new to Haskell.
EDIT - I've found a solution  - please let me know if there's a more succinct way to code it  !

```
type ProbabilityMatrix = (Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)
-- converts list of tuples into list of ints as suggested
tupleToList :: [(Int, Int)] -> [Int]  
tupleToList ((a,b):xs) = a : b : tupleToList xs  
tupleToList _          = []    

tupleToList2 :: [Int] -> ProbabilityMatrix -> ProbabilityMatrix  
tupleToList2 [] list = list  
tupleToList2 (x : xs) (zero, one, two, three, four, five, six)  
  | x == 0 =  tupleToList2 xs (zero + 1, one, two, three, four, five, six)  
  | x == 1 = tupleToList2 xs (zero, one + 1, two, three, four, five, six)  
  | x == 2 = tupleToList2 xs (zero, one, two + 1, three, four, five, six)  
  | x == 3 = tupleToList2 xs (zero, one, two, three + 1, four, five, six)  
  | x == 4 = tupleToList2 xs (zero, one, two, three, four + 1, five, six)  
  | x == 5 = tupleToList2 xs (zero, one, two, three, four, five + 1, six)  
  | x == 6 = tupleToList2 xs (zero, one, two, three, four, five, six + 1)  
  | otherwise = tupleToList2 xs (zero + 1, one, two, three, four, five, six)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can first aim to implement a counter to count the number of zeros, ones, etc.

Comment: Furthermore perhaps you better first try to process a list of `Int`s, not a list of tuples.

Comment: If you install the `multiset` package and import `Data.MultiSet`, you could use `toOccurList . fromList` to get the number of occurrences of each value in a list. Perhaps first though, you should do this the manual way, with `foldr`/`foldl` and incrementing an accumulator as you see each value in the list.

Comment: A more appropriate data structure for `ProbabilityMatrix` is an array. Check out the `array` or `vector` libraries.

Comment: 1 line: Get a list from the tuples.  2nd line: Get an array or map of the counts 3rd line: convert the array to a list (if desired) and return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you create the result list of Ints for each tuple, and then merge them together with a Sum function. You'd need at least two functions with signatures:

`tupleToList :: (Int, Int) -> [Int]`

and

`sumLists :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`

The first one will detect both items in the tuple, and generate the corresponding list for it, e.g. `tupleToList (4, 2) -> [0,0,1,0,1,0,0]`.

The second function will merge two lists of ints by summing 2 counters at the same index, e.g. `sumLists [0,1,1,0,1] [1,1,0,0,0] -> [1,2,1,0,1]`. You can do this recursively until you end up with 1 list that will be the answer to the problem.

You'd execute `tupleToList` for each of the elements in the tuple list (probably with `map`) and then consolidate the resulting list by executing `sumLists` for 2 lists iteratively (maybe with `foldl`)

This approach is rather naive and would probably run slowly for bigger inputs.

Comment: Thank you! I've created a working program now but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to write it - have added an edit to the main post

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
-- flattens a list of tuples into a list
flatten :: (Num a) => [(a, a)] -> [a]
flatten xs = concat [[a,b] | (a, b) <- xs]

-- updates list element at a position
update_list :: (Num a) => Int -> [a] -> [a]
update_list n xs = take n xs ++ [(xs !! n) + 1] ++ drop (n + 1) xs

-- performs count of numbers
count_numbers :: [(Int, Int)] -> [Int]
count_numbers xs = go (flatten xs) acc
    where go [] acc = acc
          go (x:xs) acc = go xs (update_list x acc)
          acc = replicate 7 0
```

Where it first flattens a list:

```
*Main> flatten [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)]
[0,1,1,2,2,3]
```

Then updates a list at a certain position:

```
*Main> update_list 1 (replicate 7 0)
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

And performs counting of list elements similarly to your function `tupleToList2`, where an accumulator of the number counts is stored and updated:

```
*Main> count_numbers [(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)]
[1,2,2,1,0,0,0]
*Main> count_numbers [(0,1), (1,2), (2,4)]
[1,2,2,0,1,0,0]
*Main> count_numbers [(0,0), (1,0), (3,6)]
[3,1,0,1,0,0,1]
```